# Hiberate namedquery or criteria query - for better performance?

Tags: performance, hibernate, criteria

Discussion on hibernate which I can use in my project;

Case1: I have a simple query case:

```sql
select <column> from <table> where <condition>
```

For this case, which facility of hibernate can I use - find by named query or use criteria/detached criteria - which one will be better for performance.

Case2: For join query cases, which facility would be most efficient: criteria/detached criteria or use a reference VO [referring to foreign key table] inside my parent VO[referring to parent Table]

Answer (score 1):

> Case1: I have a simple query case: select from where
>
> For this case, which facility of hibernate can I use - find by named query or
>   use criteria/detached criteria - which one will be better for performance.

The only performance difference you will see between the two is based on query parse time.  In the case of a *Named Query* the query will be parsed at bootup of hibernate once and reused.  If you used a *Criterion Query* the query will be parsed at each execution point at runtime.

> Case2: For join query cases, which facility would be most efficient: 
>   criteria/detached criteria or use a reference VO [referring to foreign key 
>   table] inside my parent VO[referring to parent Table]

Unless your join-query is again a named query, you're going to incur the same performance issues as above, mainly in the area of parsing the query into SQL.

As for whether you elect to use the Hibernate/JPA criteria API or JPQL/HQL; it's really a matter of taste.

The most crucial performance concern you likely should be considering when using an ORM is to make sure your fetch strategies are adequate and that the proper joins are used to avoid things such as N+1 SELECT concerns.

Making adequate use of tuple-queries or construct-new value-object queries can go a long way to minimize network bandwidth when the entities being queried are wide and you have several being joined together for some UI view.

Comment: Thanks Naros for your response. I will read it again and try to grasp the concept/answer that you are telling but when I read it few times, I have few questions;

Comment: 1. Namedquery would be parsed at bootup of hibernate but criteria query at each execution point at runtime - So this will mean namedQuery is better to use than criteria query? You also have mentioned that performance difference will be there in runtime , but sorry, I really could not understand it much because namedquery seems to have better performance in general since it do not require parsing every time as opposed to criteria query?

Comment: case2: Choosing the method is a matter of taste but if namedquery is better so I can go for it always? Sorry if these questions are not good. Thanks once again for nice response.

Comment: Yes, `NamedQuery`s are parsed once and so tend to be a tad more efficient because of that fact during runtime.  But sometimes, `NamedQuery`s are not possible just given the dynamic nature of some queries and so a `Creation` based query is better.  I wouldn't be worried so much about parsing cost of a query as I would other costs such as execution time of the query itself on the database.